# Purely numerical permalinks in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I want to use purely numerical permalinks for my wordpress page .As it is ,it adds a "-2" at the end of the slug which is not what i want . I looked at this link [Purely numerical wordpress permalinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007881/purely-numerical-wordpress-permalinks)
but i don't really understand how to use the function given there .

Comment: To use the function you linked to, you'd add it to your theme's `functions.php` file. I don't know if the function actually works, but that's how you'd use it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a workaround , redirecting all [ **example.com/page-2.html** ] links to  [ **example.com/page.html** ] using this wordpress plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/