# Allow Numeric Slugs for Wordpress CPT

Tags: wordpress, slug

Is that possible to **Allow Numeric Slugs** (without -2) for custom post type without plugins?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Purely numerical wordpress permalinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007881/purely-numerical-wordpress-permalinks)

Comment: Nope( His function automatically rewrites slug to MD5

Comment: But I would like to switch off any rewrites.